# I have json response that i want to display into kendow window?

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have json response using rest service now i want to populate that data into my html page using Angularjs expression binding, i have tried to get data in one field but i failed to rendered. any help will be appreciated.

So far i have tried this...

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="lrrSearchModalCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label">Jurisdiction</label> 
        <p>-EMEA -United</p>
        <p>- Kingdom</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Rule Id</label>
            <div>{{ ruleIdentifier.id }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">SubpartID</label>
            <div>{{subpartId}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Rule Internal or Outsourced</label>
            <div>Rule internal data</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Subpart Internal or Outsourced</label>
            <div>LRR Data one lorem i</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Rule Citation</label>
            <div>MSRB Gen Rule G-37</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Subpart Citation</label>
            <div>29 CFR 2550.401c-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

searchCtrl.JS

```
$scope.lrrDetailWinOptions = lrrSearchGridConfig.modalLrrConfig;
    $scope.showDetail = function (id){
      $scope.selectedId = id;
      $scope.lrrDetailWin.open().center();
    }
```

ModalCTRL.JS

```
angular.module('thirdPartyManagementApp').controller('lrrSearchModalCtrl', function($scope,lrrDetails) {
    'use strict';
    var result = {
        ruleIdentifier:{},
        subpartId: {}

    }
    lrrDetails.findlrrDetail().then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    })

   $scope.ruleIdentifier = result.ruleIdentifier
   $scope.subpartId = getLrrData.subpartId


   $scope.showDetail = function(id){

   }

 });
```

JSON.JS

```
{"id":1,
"sourceFeedKey":15,
"lookupCode":"RS_DELETED",
"externalIndintifier":"47",
"subpartCitationIndicator":"1",
"ruleIdentifier":"13",
"ruleSubpartExternalIdentifier":"55029",
"subpartCount":null,
"subpartCitationCount":null,
"citationValue":"18 U.S.C. 2711",
"ruleName":"Definitions For Chapter",
"highValueSummary":"This chapter provides guidance on stored wire and electronic communications and transactional 
records access and contains provisions of the Stored Communications 
Act.","
issuingAuthKey":873,
"citationAsOfDate":1325566800000,
"vedourActivityType":"Internal Activity",
"vedourActivityDescription1":null,
"vedourActivityDescription2":null,
"applicabilityIndicator":"0",
"auditGroupCategory":null,
"auditGroupIndicator":null,
"citationCoreIndicator":null,
"createdDate":1352497145890,
"modifiedDate":1375313477250,
"createdBy":"ERDSYSTEM",
"mofifiedBy":"NBKQNXS",
"regulatoryInventoryName":{
"id":2,
"inventoryName":"Electronic Communication",
"erhKey":null,
"regInvetoryclassKey":null,
"ntrntlFlag":true},
"regulatoryInventoryClassfication":{
"id":1,
"classificationName":"Compliance",
"sponserWrokerKey":6411},

"geographicLocations":[
{"id":21598,
"sourceFeedKey":5,
"lookupCode":"RS_ACTIVE",
"externalIndintifier":"1",
"geoLocationTransactionKey":0,
"geoLocationCode":"USA",
"geoLocationName":"United States",
"geoLocationShortName":" ",
"regionIdentifier":1,
"regionName":"United States"}],

"enterpriseReportingHierarchies":[
{"id":161,
"erhTransactionKey":161,
"erhName":"Enterprise Privacy Compliance",
"erhShortName":"LCRR",
"erhLevelNumber":4,
"parentId":3320,
"level0Id":0,
"level0Name":"BAC Enterprise Wide",
"level1Id":804,
"level1Name":"Legal Compliance and Regulatory Relations",
"level2Id":167,
"level2Name":"Global Compliance",
"level3Id":3320,
"level3Name":"Enterprise Compliance",
"level4Id":175,
"level4Name":"Enterprise Privacy Compliance","activeIndicator":"1"}]}
```

Comment: i could not display json data to html..

Comment: i am new to angularjs i would like to know implementation in controller and html

Comment: What does it mean "could not display"? Some error? Strange results? Please note that SO is not a tutorial place. It is to help help that got stuck in a piece of their code.

Comment: i think as new to angularjs i am stuck into implementation of controller and using expression , e.g ruleidentifier response from json how i can get value of ruleidentifier in html...its simple question i asked.

Comment: Is anything output in the console?

Comment: yes Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you should have:

```
lrrDetails.findlrrDetail().then(function(response){
  $scope.lrrDetail = response;
})
```

Then in the view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Rule Id</label>
        <div>{{ lrrDetail.id }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">SubpartID</label>
        <div>{{lrrDetail.ruleSubpartExternalIdentifier}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, use whatever fields make sense.